# Connecting dimension tables in a multi-fact star schema database warehouse?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I am new to data warehouse modelling so please bear with me.

In database warehouse modelling, the star schema is typically a fact table with multiple dimensions connected directly to it. However, what if there are two or more fact tables in the schema and some of the dimensions are related? Please see below as an example:

[image]

Is it **allow** to draw a line to relate the dimension tables in star schema database warehouse modelling? For example, assume `dim_a` is `hotel_rooms` and `dim_d` is `customers`, can I draw the line between the two table in the star schema since a hotel room has many customers staying?

In all the examples I searched online, the star schema is always connected to dimension tables and these tables are not drawn with a line to connect it.

Comment: There's already two many-to-many relationships between `dim_a` and `dim_d` in your diagram codified as `fact_1` and `fact_2`. This would render any relationship directly from `dim_a` to `dim_d` suspect or the relationships to `fact_1` and `fact_2`.

Comment: If you were trying to associate customers to rooms, you usually would have a Booking or Occupancy fact table to express that relationship and necessary details.

Comment: Hey there! Sorry I do not understand what you mean. What do you mean by suspect? I can't see the many-to-many relationship (the lines are basically one to many).

Comment: Suspect as in redundant or possibly breaking a business rule.  If two entities have a one-to-many relationship to another entity, they have a many-to-many relationship through that entity (although it may be trivial or not make sense in a business context).

Comment: I see. Assuming if `fact_2` and `dim_d` are gone. Is `dim_b` and `dim_a` association allow in the star schema modelling?

Comment: Not unless there was a parent/child relationship (e.g. country -> state -> city)

Comment: Thanks bbaird. May I ask based on what we discussed, is it consider a conceptual or logical data warehouse modelling design?

Comment: There's just "a model".  It starts as logical, that logical becomes part of the physical model as it progresses.

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple fact tables in a model is pretty common and is sometimes referred as a **Fact Constellation**. The shared dimensions are referred as **Conformed Dimensions**.

As @bbaird said in the comment there shouldn't be a direct one-to-many relationship between dim_a (hotel_rooms) and dim_d (customers) as this relationship should be modeled through a fact table (booking, reservation, stay, ...).

Relationships between dimensions are mainly used to drill-down from one level to another (for instance over a geographical area or as you modeled it for the time dimension). A model with dimensions linked like that is referred as a **Snowflake**. It is often also possible to flatten these hierarchical levels into a single dimension which might add complexity to maintain but provide better performance on some RDBMS.